# JRebel with CTRL + F9

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts2, maven-3, jrebel

I am using maven project with struts2, Tiles, XML Validation, Properties and Tomcat 7 maven plugin.

Using Maven Tomcat 7 plugin and run with JRebel to test my work and changes. Changes to `-validation.xml`, `struts.xml` and `tiles.xml` are not reflected with JRebel. May be there are plugin to work with struts etc.

**What I do:**

I run Tomcat 7 instance as JRebel and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F9</kbd> (make project) if I make any changes to `-validation.xml`, `struts.xml` and `tiles.xml` or even create any file. I refresh the browser and changes are updated without stopping/starting Tomcat with JRebel.

**I was wondering, Is this the right approach or am I missing something?**

[image: JRebel]

**EDITED:**

```
Struts2 version = 2.3.4.1
struts2-Tiles-Plugin = 2.3.4.1
Tiles-Core = 2.0.6

No xml filtering
struts.devMode=true
```

*I see all the xml files in the classes folder of target directory.*

***rebel.xml -> I see it in the target folder and is created.***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.zeroturnaround.com" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.zeroturnaround.com http://www.zeroturnaround.com/alderaan/rebel-2_0.xsd">

    <classpath>
        <dir name="C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/Java/Projects/1_Struts2_Tiles_mvn/target/classes">
        </dir>
    </classpath>

    <web>
        <link target="/">
            <dir name="C:/Users/mypc/Desktop/Java/Projects/1_Struts2_Tiles_mvn/src/main/webapp">
            </dir>
        </link>
    </web>

</application>
```

**Project Structure**

[image: Project]

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Struts and Tiles do you use? Changes to struts.xml and tiles.xml should definitely be picked up by JRebel. Not sure what's the validation.xml file for in your case.

Secondly, did you include rebel.xml configuration file to the package?

Answer (score 0):

Are you filtering the .xml files by Maven (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html)? In that case JRebel won't reload your changes.
Are the struts.devMode=true in your struts.properties or struts.xml?

Do you have checked the struts2 plugin option in JRebel Configuration?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please run try the nightly version of JRebel. There was a change in Struts 2.3.4 that broke our integration for it. This has been fixed in the nightly build, please use that and see whether it helps any. Link to nightly: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/download/early-access/

Secondly, the contents of your rebel.xml looks correct. Make sure that the rebel.xml is in the target/classes directory. It should go to the root of a .jar file (when building a .jar module) or to WEB-INF/classes (when building a .war module).

Are changes to classes or other resources reloaded by JRebel in your running application? If other modifications are indeed reloaded and just the configuration in those .xml files is not, then please send us your jrebel.log file to support@zeroturnaround.com for a session where the issue occurs. See here for instructions on enabling JRebel logging: http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/sending-log/. From the log file I can check from where JRebel finds the various .xml files and whether it tries to reload them after they are updated in the filesystem.